# Building a nested query in SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and having trouble to build a query:

I have three tables:

Customers of a magazines store:

```
Customer(cid, name)
```

the magazines

```
Magazine(mid, topic)
```

the subscriptions for the magazines:

```
Subscribes(cid, mid)
```

How do I build a query that will show the customers that are subscribed to only one magazine with condition that all other customers subscribed to that one magazine are subscribed to at least one other magazine?

I managed to build a query (not sure if absolutely correct) that shows customers that are subscribed to only one magazine and stuck here:

```
select customer.cid, customer.name, count(subscribes.mid)
from subscribes, customer
where subscribes.cid=customer.cid 

group by customer.cid
having count(subscribes.mid)=1
```

Comment: show what you did so far.

Comment: I summarized the question to have less irrelevant details... My solution is a mess..

Comment: your solution may be a mess but answers don't exist -- this is not hard we can all do it, but we want to see that you tried before we spend the time to do your work.

Comment: updated my question...

Comment: you are grouping by customer and looking for count to be one -- it will always be one. since you are grouping by it.  you have the group by reversed, you want count of subscriptions

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3):

> How do I build a query that will show me the customers that are
>   subscribed to only one magazine with condition that all other
>   customers subscribed to that magazine are subscribed to at least one
>   other magazine?

You had the right idea take it step by step.

Customers subscribed to only one magazine

```
 SELECT cid
 FROM subscribes
 GROUP BY cid
 HAVING COUNT(mid) = 1
```

Customers subscribed to two or more magazines

```
SELECT cid
FROM subscribes
GROUP BY cid 
HAVING COUNT(mid) > 1
```

Customers and the number of magazines they subscribe to

```
SELECT cid, count(mid) as s_count
FROM subscribes
GROUP BY cid
```

so

```
WITH cust_and_count AS
(
  SELECT cid, count(mid) as s_count
  FROM subscribes
  GROUP BY cid
)
SELECT cust_and_count.cid, s1.mid
FROM cust_and_count -- with the where below this gives us all users subscribed to a single mag
-- Get the magazine of users that have one subscription
JOIN subscribes s1 on cust_and_count.cid = s1.cid
-- Join that magazine back to who subscribes exclude our starting guys
JOIN subscribes s2 on s1.mid = s2.mid and s2.cid != cust_and_count.cid
-- Join back to our counts and make sure it is greater than 1
JOIN cust_and_count c2 on s2.cid = c2.cid and c2.s_count > 1
WHERE cust_and_count.s_count = 1
```

> note, table names are typically not plural -- all tables have rows you typically name it by what a single element would be called, so customer, magazine, subscription in your case.

Comment: @tshoemake - good point -- forgot to go back and put something interesting there.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88deb/6  if you run this it returns cid 2 and 5 which technically arent correct because both are only subbed to mag 1, however you're excluding them in your 2nd join.

Comment: @Hogan, for that fiddle the output should be 2,4,5,6? Do you agree? See what does my select returns http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88deb/9  And the question: how can it happen that correct answer scoes -1 and incorrect +3?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, the fiddle should select only 2 and 5 if anything.  If you look at cid's 4 and 6 (both subbed to mag 2), there are no other customers subscribed to mag 2 other than 4 and 6.  Thus they shouldn't be returned in the result set.

Comment: @tshoemake, there are no other costomers! So `that all other customers subscribed to THAT ONE magazine` this is satisfied because there are no other customers.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri please re read my previous comment using the fiddle as a reference for an explanation as to why

Comment: hmmm it seems 2 and 5 should not be returned I need another condition

Comment: @Hogan, in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/860e7/2 the only correct answer that should be return is 6.

Comment: Guys, first you say it is correct answer, then you say wrong, then say 2 5 shouldn't be there, then should, then shouldn't :)

Comment: You are all completely lost. Why 6?? 6 has mag2. With your logic all others which have mag2 i.e. cust4 has to have another mag but cust4 has only one mag2! Then why 6 and only 6 is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The following query selects all the customers subscribed to only 1 magazine:

```
SELECT *
FROM Subscribes
GROUP BY cid
HAVING COUNT(Subscribes.mid) = 1
```

This query selects all the customers other than `C` for magazine `M` with 1 subscription:

```
SELECT 1
FROM Subscribes
WHERE mid = M
      AND cid != C
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Subscribes
                  WHERE cid = Subscribes.cid
                  AND COUNT(mid) <= 1)
```

And this, I believe, would do what you ask in the question:

```
SELECT *
FROM Subscribes
GROUP BY cid
HAVING COUNT(Subscribes.mid) = 1 as SingleSubs
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM Subscribes
                       WHERE mid = SingleSubs.mid
                             AND cid != SingleSubs.cid
                             AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                         FROM Subscribes
                                         WHERE cid = Subscribes.cid
                                         AND COUNT(mid) <= 1))
```

Explanation:

```
SELECT (All cid, mid with 1 subscription) as SingleSubs
WHERE NOT EXISTS (All customers other than SingleSubs.cid with 1 subscription)
```

Answer (score 0):

Must give credit to @Hogan...

Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/860e7/4

Code:

```
;WITH cust_and_count AS
(
  SELECT cid, count(mid) as s_count
  FROM subs
  GROUP BY cid
)
SELECT distinct c1.cid
FROM cust_and_count c1
JOIN subs s1 on c1.cid = s1.cid
JOIN subs s2 on s1.mid = s2.mid and s2.cid != c1.cid and s1.mid >1
WHERE c1.s_count = 1
```

Comment: Ohh man 6 2 is the row of the same power as 4 2. Why do you think that 6 is the only correct man?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri #1 condition met: C2, C4, C5, C6 are all subbed to only one mag. C2 is subbed to mag 1, but C5 is also ONLY subbed to mag 1. C5 is subbed to mag 1, but C2 is also ONLY subbed to mag 1. C4 is subbed to mag 2 but no one else is (we need customers subbed to mag 2 AND another mag in order for C4 to qualify). #2 condition met: C6 is subbed to mag 3.  C1 & C3 are both subbed to mag 3 and BOTH are subbed to another mag (mag 1).  C6 is the only result.

Comment: Great, you just changed 2 to 3. I changed 3 to 2 and your select returns 4 and 6.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri ok, but do you understand now?

Comment: Yes now I get you. But I understand the question other way. You want to exclude such cases like 2 diff custs subscribed to same mag and have both only that mag.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is asked correctly then the answer is:

```
select cid from subscribers
group by cid
having count(mid) = 1
```

because:

> How do I build a query that will show the customers that are
>   subscribed to only one magazine with condition that all other
>   customers subscribed to that one magazine are subscribed to at least
>   one other magazine?

The query returns subscribers that are subscribed to only 1 magazine. Your second condition automatically applies, because other way the other customer will be in result set. I.e. if other customer is subscribed to some magazine in the output and that customer is not in output, that means he is subscribed more then to 1 magazine including current one.

If you want to exclude pairs of customers with same magazine then:

```
select max(cid)
from(select cid, max(mid) mid from subs
     group by cid
     having count(mid) = 1) t
group by mid
having count(cid) = 1
```